# VB.NET - Parallel.For is Slower than Sequential For

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I am trying to use parallel processing in order to separate data depending by its content.

In the following example I generate random numbers and I want to store them to datatables if fulfill the a condition.

For my disappointment the sequential for works faster than parallel.

Is it doable to make parallel to work faster?

```
Imports System.Random
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class Form1
    Public No As Integer = 5
    Public DT(No) As DataTable
    Public S(No) As String
    Public StartTimer As DateTime
    Private Sub ParrallelProc_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ParrallelProc_Btn.Click
        For j = 1 To No
            DT(j).Rows.Clear()
        Next
        StartTimer = Now
        For k = 1 To 10000
            Parallel.For(1, No + 1, Sub(i)
                                        Dim CurrentNo As String = CStr(Math.Round(Rnd() * 1000000, 0))
                                        If CurrentNo.Contains(S(i)) Then DT(i).Rows.Add(CurrentNo)
                                    End Sub)
        Next
        Dim Interval = Now.Subtract(StartTimer).TotalSeconds
    End Sub

    Private Sub SequentialProc_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SequentialProc_Btn.Click
        For j = 1 To No
            DT(j).Rows.Clear()
        Next
        StartTimer = Now
        For k = 1 To 10000
            For l = 1 To No
                Dim CurrentNo As String = CStr(Math.Round(Rnd() * 1000000, 0))
                If CurrentNo.Contains(S(l)) Then DT(l).Rows.Add(CurrentNo)
            Next
        Next
        Dim Interval = Now.Subtract(StartTimer).TotalSeconds
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Questionable benchmark, use Stopwatch to get more accurate timing.  Do beware that Rnd() is not thread-safe, it can't generate sufficiently random sequences when used in more than one thread.  If you want somebody else to run this code then show what S() contains.

Comment: S() array can contain a 2 digit string (eg 12 or 36 etc). Regarding the benchmark method, at this point is not very important. The duration of the parallel method is 7 secs and the sequential is about 0.5 secs

Comment: Parallel.For won't help if you only looping 5 times. The overhead is to much for that.Try to change the loop so that Parallel.For works 50.000 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, not to brag, but my PC runs the parallel in 160ms, and the sequential in 40ms.

There is some overhead in creating threads, and with only 5 threads it's unnecessary - you might as well just do the 5 things. Especially something as lightweight as what you've got. Parallelization is made for doing multiple long-ish running tasks at the same time.

Eventually, the parallel loop is faster, once you've overcome the thread overhead. I've tested with increasing `No`, and this happens at around 100.

```
Public No As Integer = 100
Public DT(No) As DataTable
Public S(No) As String
Public StartTimer As DateTime
Private iterations As Integer = 10000

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i = 1 To No
        DT(i) = New DataTable()
        DT(i).Columns.Add()
        S(i) = (i + 1).ToString()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ParallelProc_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ParallelProc_Btn.Click
    clearDT()
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    For k = 1 To iterations
        Parallel.For(
            1,
            No + 1,
            AddressOf process)
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
End Sub

Private Sub SequentialProc_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SequentialProc_Btn.Click
    clearDT()
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    For k = 1 To iterations
        For i = 1 To No
            process(i)
        Next
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
End Sub

Private Sub clearDT()
    For j = 1 To No
        DT(j).Rows.Clear()
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub process(i As Integer)
    Randomize()
    Dim CurrentNo As String = CStr(Math.Round(Rnd() * 1000000, 0))
    If CurrentNo.Contains(S(i)) Then DT(i).Rows.Add(CurrentNo)
End Sub
```

I also moved the operation to a Sub which can be called by both routines. Reuse your code not only to save time and space, but also to ensure you are just comparing the methods, not the routines.

You should also call `Randomize()` before using `Rnd()`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y66ey2hh(v=vs.110).aspx

A better test would be to put something of substance in the `process()` method like a `Thread.Sleep(1)`, and play with `No` and `iterations`. You will find that sleeping in parallel is much more efficient than sleeping in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Put the smaller loop in the bigger loop and it should make the parallel loop much faster that the sequential.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Module Module1
Public Sub Main()

    Dim Rnd as New Random()
    Dim _sw as new Stopwatch

    _sw.Restart()
    For k = 1 To 1000
        Parallel.For(1, 6, Sub(i)
            Dim CurrentNo As Double = Rnd.Next()
            ' Do other stuff
        End Sub)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(_sw.Elapsed) 
    ' >> took 00:00:00.0659017 on dotnetfiddle.net

    _sw.Restart()
    Parallel.For(1, 1000+1, Sub(k)
        For i as Integer = 1 to 5
            Dim CurrentNo As Double = Rnd.Next()
            ' Do other stuff
        Next
    End Sub)

    Console.WriteLine(_sw.Elapsed)
    ' >> took 00:00:00.0009715 on dotnetfiddle.net

End Sub

End Module
```